# Black screen flash during video

Tags: drivers, sound, video, hdmi

I am watching videos, not in full screen but full window, running from my laptop to tv via hdmi, at random moments the tv goes black for a second and loses sound but video does not stop.

Is there something I have to do with the hdmi drivers to get smooth signal to the tv?

I just changed from one laptop to the other and my original laptop I was using never had this problem. Both are running Mint 17.3 and kodi 15.2 if that helps.

Now after stopping my video to run updates to try and fix it I noticed it blacks out even when not playing video.

Comment: so I've been researching my issue and I think it boils down to hat my graphics card is an: "AMD RS880M Mobility Rdeon HD 4225/4250 and AMD no longer makes drivers for anything older then 5000 and my version of Linux is too new to run the older drivers.

Comment: I have the same problem on a brand new Dell XPS13 (2016) with Intel HD Graphics 5500